# Generate random number for each row in between range

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark; I am trying to generate a random number for each row in Spark between range `1` to `30`, something like:

```
import scala.util.Random

df.withColumn("random_num", lit(Random.nextInt(30)))
```

Expected output:

```
col1     1
col      2
abc      1
bcd      3
xyz      6
hg       2
```

How can I do that?

NOTE: I have 7 billion rows to process, so I wanted to assign a random number to each row, so that I can use that columns for my repartition as further needed to me.
`monotonically_increasing_id` is not applicable in my case as it generated random number but not in range and very uneven  manner. I wanted to assign some numbers to 7B rows which would be somehow optimal and equal, so that when I use that column for reparation, I should avoid any skewness.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rand` method from Spark, rather than a Java method, for example, if this was your `data`:

```
+----+
|col |
+----+
|col1|
|col2|
|abc |
|bcd |
|xyz |
|hg  |
+----+
```

Then, this statement:

```
data = data.withColumn("random_num", round(rand().multiply(30)))
```

Generates this output:

```
+----+----------+
|col |random_num|
+----+----------+
|col1|24.0      |
|col2|16.0      |
|abc |20.0      |
|bcd |26.0      |
|xyz |8.0       |
|hg  |22.0      |
+----+----------+
```

Good luck!

**EDIT**

If your data is skewed, assigning and partitioning by a unique ID per row will crash your application, you can consider adding [salt](https://towardsdatascience.com/skewed-data-in-spark-add-salt-to-compensate-16d44404088b?gi=7669aa2eeb22) or read more about it [here](https://itnext.io/handling-data-skew-in-apache-spark-9f56343e58e8).